# Will The Aws sdk for C++ refresh the assumed role once the time for assumed role is expired using STS?

Tags: aws-sts, aws-sdk-cpp

I have a use case where i have to assume a role using ARN to access S3 resource but my concern is that will the STS automatically refresh the credentials once the time for assumed role is expired. The auto assuming role is present in Java Aws sdk but i want to know is it the same in Aws Sdk in c++.